# How to implement 3d effect zooming in viewpager android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-viewpager

I need help regarding the viewpager. Basically I have a viewpager contained in a page container:

```
package com.example.CustomViews;

/**
 * Created by imrankhan on 4/29/2015.
 */

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Camera;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.Transformation;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.example.imrankhan.newlawdojo.DashboardActivity;
import com.example.imrankhan.newlawdojo.QuizActivity;
import com.example.imrankhan.newlawdojo.R;

/**
 * PagerContainer: A layout that displays a ViewPager with its children that are outside
 * the typical pager bounds.
 */
public class PageContainer extends FrameLayout implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

    private ViewPager mPager;
    boolean mNeedsRedraw = false;

    private Camera mCamera = new Camera();

    private int mMaxRotationAngle = 60;

    private int mMaxZoom = -120;

    public PageContainer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public PageContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public PageContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        //Disable clipping of children so non-selected pages are visible
        setClipChildren(false);

        //Child clipping doesn't work with hardware acceleration in Android 3.x/4.x
        //You need to set this value here if using hardware acceleration in an
        // application targeted at these releases.
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        try {
            mPager = (ViewPager) getChildAt(0);
            mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The root child of PagerContainer must be a ViewPager");
        }
    }

    public ViewPager getViewPager() {
        return mPager;
    }

    private Point mCenter = new Point();
    private Point mInitialTouch = new Point();

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        mCenter.x = w / 4;
        mCenter.y = h / 4;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        //We capture any touches not already handled by the ViewPager
        // to implement scrolling from a touch outside the pager bounds.
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                mInitialTouch.x = (int)ev.getX();
                mInitialTouch.y = (int)ev.getY();
            default:
                ev.offsetLocation(mCenter.x - mInitialTouch.x, mCenter.y - mInitialTouch.y);
                break;
        }

        return mPager.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        //Force the container to redraw on scrolling.
        //Without this the outer pages render initially and then stay static
        if (mNeedsRedraw) invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    View v =this.getViewPager().getChildAt(position);

    }
    private void transformImageBitmap(View child, Transformation t, int rotationAngle) {
        mCamera.save();
        final Matrix imageMatrix = t.getMatrix();;
        final int imageHeight = child.getLayoutParams().height;;
        final int imageWidth = child.getLayoutParams().width;
        final int rotation = Math.abs(rotationAngle);
        mCamera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);

        if ( rotation < mMaxRotationAngle ) {
            float zoomAmount = (float) (mMaxZoom +  (rotation * 1.5));
            mCamera.translate(0.0f, 0.0f, zoomAmount);
        }

        mCamera.rotateY(rotationAngle);
        mCamera.getMatrix(imageMatrix);

        imageMatrix.preTranslate(-(imageWidth/2), -(imageHeight/2));

        imageMatrix.postTranslate((imageWidth/2), (imageHeight/2));

        mCamera.restore();

    }
    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        mNeedsRedraw = (state != ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE);
    }
}
```

on `onPageSelected` event I got the view I need to zoom in when selected and zoom out after selecting another item. Please help me out. I added an image to give you an idea what I want.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtE89.png